# Como insertar un salto de linea en archivo de texto generado desde una app apache cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Hola a todos estoy generando un archivo de texto desde una aplicacion hecha con apache cordova  el codigo que estoy usando es el siguiente llebo muchas noches en esto

con este controlador angular  me traigo el texto de la base de datos en json  y luego le quito las llaves  [{}:]""

y lo guardo en un localStorage.

```
.controller('cargaObj', function ($scope, $http) {

 $scope.load = function () {


        var datos;
        var selectAllStatement = "SELECT barcode,codigo,descripcion,capacidad,cantidad FROM ordenes where codigo <> '0' and descripcion <> 'undefined' and descripcion <> '------------------------------                              '";
        var db = openDatabase("AddressBook", "1.0", "AddressBook", 200000);  // Open SQLite Database
        var dataset;
        var DataType;
        function initDatabase()  // Function Para iniciar la base de datos local y llamar la tabla
        {
            try {
                if (!window.openDatabase)  // Check browser is supported SQLite or not.
                {
                    alert('Base de datos no soportada.');
                }
                else {
                    createTable();  // If supported then call Function for create table in SQLite
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                if (e == 2) {
                    console.log("Version no valida.");
                } else {
                    console.log("Error " + e + ".");
                }
                return;
            }
        }
        /* document.getElementById("btnconfirma").style.display = 'block'; */
            /* document.getElementById("btnini").style.display = 'block'; */
  showRecords();

  function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list
        {
            var res = "";
            $("#results").html('')
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {
                    dataset = result.rows;

                    var cad = JSON.stringify(dataset);
                    var cad2 = cad.split('}');

                for(var cadena of cad2) {    
                    var cad = cadena.indexOf(":");
                console.log("Completa... " + cad);  

                     res = res  +  cadena.substring(cad + 1, cadena.length) + "}<br>" ;                                          
                }

              /* var r = "["+ res.substring(0, res.length - 15) + "]";   asi estaba*/          
            var r = "["+ res.substring(0, res.length - 15);
           alert("ya"+r)
            someString = r;
            sinllave = someString.replace("[", '');
            sincorchete = sinllave.replace(/{/g, "");
            anotherString = sincorchete.replace(/barcode/g, '');            
            sinpuntos = anotherString.replace(/:/g, "");
            sincodigo = sinpuntos.replace(/codigo/g, '');
            sindescripcion= sincodigo.replace(/descripcion/g, '');
            sincapacidad = sindescripcion.replace(/capacidad/g, '');
            sincantidad = sincapacidad.replace(/cantidad/g, '');                            
            sinllaveI = sincantidad.replace(/]/g, '');
            sinCorchI = sinllaveI.replace(/}/g, ",0");          
            listo = sinCorchI.replace(/"/g, "");
            var lineas = listo;
            var str_array = lineas.split(',');
            var arr = [];

                for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
                    str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
                    arr.push(str_array[i])
                }

                localStorage.setItem("data", arr);
            /* var G =  arr.substring(0, arr.length - 5); */


              $scope.items = JSON.parse(r);    

              });
            });            
        }
 }

})
```

con este script imprimo el texto usando el plugin file de apache cordova

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {

            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
        }

        function gotFS(fileSystem) {
          var pedido = localStorage.getItem("pedido");

            fileSystem.root.getFile(pedido+".txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
        }

      function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
            alert("write success");
        };
     var data = localStorage.getItem("data");

        writer.write(data);
    }
        function fail(error) {
            alert(error.code);
        }
        </script>
```

cuando instalo la app y la pruebo el texto que me arroja tiene la siguiente cadena

```
7500112374288,C1300202,VINIMEX TOTAL SATINADO BLANCO,CUB,4,0<br>7500112374356,C1300223,VINIMEX TOTAL SATINADO VIVID V2,GAL,1,0<br>7500112374448,C1300253,VINIMEX TOTAL SATINADO VIVID V5,GAL,1,0<br>7500112437679,C1042183,TOP 5 A�OS SEC RAP BLANCO FOTOSENSIBLE,GAL,3
```

lo veo asi en mi telefono

-->>[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna suferencia ? les agradezco de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por lo que veo, en esta linea hace una comparación y reemplaza un valor por otro `str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");` deberías, entonces, hacer una comparación con el salto de linea `<br>` y reemplazarlo por el `'\n'`

Comment: hola eduardo gracias por aportar, el <br> se lo pongo manualmente ene sta linea  res = res  +  cadena.substring(cad + 1, cadena.length) + "}<br>" ;  si lo pongo  de esta manera 
 res = res  +  cadena.substring(cad + 1, cadena.length) + "}"+"/n" ; igualmente me imprime el salto de linea en el texto cuando lo genero

Comment: La solución no va en la pregunta, edita y agrega la en la zona respectiva

Comment: listo señor editado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la respuesta fue reemplazar  la ultima llave del json con un '/r/n'  que signfican salto de linea lo equivalente a un nueva linea y una vuelta de carro  quedando asi esa linea de codigo

sinCorchI = sinllaveI.replace(/}/g, ",0"+'/r/n');